# Jenkins job: ignore error

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have a jenkins job which executes a shell script.
The last step of the shell script is deleting the docker images which are on the server (except the images which are in use).
This is my command:

```
set +x
docker rmi `docker images -aq`
```

output:

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 69a777edb6dc (must be forced) - image is referenced in one or more repositories
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 69a777edb6dc (must be forced) - image is referenced in one or more repositories
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete d9d7acd2e160 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 4e5ba6ffeaf0
```

How am I able to ignore the errors (because it's normal) + hiding the output of the command? (tried set +x but did not help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
docker 2>/dev/null 1>&2 rmi `docker images -aq` || true
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

> docker 2>/dev/null rmi `docker images -aq` | true

(only one pipe line)

Comment: Nice -- I didn't know the trick with piping into `true` : ) It hurts readability a bit, though.

Comment: Plus, outcome depends on the environment: `set -o pipefail ; false | true ; echo $?` gives `1`, not `0`.